# implementation of the random number generator in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, random

I am a bit confused by the implementation of the random number generator in C, which is also apparently different from that in C++

If I understand correctly, a call to 'srand(seed)' somehow initializes a hidden variable (the seed) that is accessible by 'rand()', which in turn points the function to a pre-generated sequence, like for [example this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946622/implementation-of-random-number-generator). Each successive call to 'rand()' advances the sequence (and apparently there are other ways to advance in C++), which also suggests the use of an internal hidden pointer or counter to keep track of the advance.

I have found many discussions on how the algorithms for pseudo-random number generation work and the documentation of the functions rand() and srand(), but haven't been able to find information about these hidden parameters and their behavior, except for the fact that [according to this source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/), they are not thread-safe.

1. Could anybody here please shed some light as to how are these parameters defined and what should be their defined behavior according to the standards, or if their behavior is implementation-defined?
2. Are they expected to be local to the function/method that calls rand() and srand()? If so, is there a way to communicate them to another function/method?

If your answer is specific to either C or C++, please be so kind to point it out. Any information will be much appreciated. Please bear in mind that this question is not about the [predictability of data generated by rand() and srand()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690226/can-rand-be-used-to-generate-predictable-data), but about the requirements, status and functioning of their internal variables as well as their accessibility and scope.

Comment: A sample implementation of `srand()` and `rand()` can be found in the C standard; see the [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), section 7.22.2. That's only a sample, but it should give you an idea. The same section defines the requirements for both functions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690226/can-rand-be-used-to-generate-predictable-data

Comment: Thanks Kevin Thompson for the reference.

Comment: I consider my question significantly different to the one referred as a duplicate. That question doesn't ask about the scope and accessibility of the internal variables of rand() and srand(). That question is about repeatability. If the information I ask had been available in that post I wouldn't have started a new question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The requirements on `rand` are:

- Generates pseudo-random numbers.
- Range is 0 to `RAND_MAX` (minimum of 32767).
- The seed set by `srand()` determines the sequence of pseudo-random numbers returned.
- It need not be thread-safe or even reentrant, the state can be stored in a static variable.

The standard does not define any way to recover the internal state for reseeding or anything else.

There is no requirement on what PRNG is implemented, so every implementation can have its own, though [Linear Congrueantial Generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) are a favorite.

A conforming (though arguably useless) implementation is presented in this dilbert strip:

http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/

Or for those who like XKCD (It's a perfect drop-in for any C or C++ library ;-)):

[image]

For completeness, the standard quotes:

> #### 7.22.2.1 The **rand** function
>
> The **rand** function computes a sequence of pseudo-random integers in the range 0 to
>   **RAND_MAX**.
>   The **rand** function is not required to avoid data races with other calls to pseudo-random
>   sequence generation functions. The implementation shall behave as if no library function
>   calls the **rand** function.
>   [...]
>   The value of the **RAND_MAX** macro shall be at least 32767.
>
> #### 7.22.2.2 The **srand** function
>
> The **srand** function uses the argument as a seed for a new sequence of pseudo-random
>   numbers to be returned by subsequent calls to **rand**. If **srand** is then called with the
>   same seed value, the sequence of pseudo-random numbers shall be repeated. If **rand** is
>   called before any calls to **srand** have been made, the same sequence shall be generated
>   as when **srand** is first called with a seed value of 1.
>   The **srand** function is not required to avoid data races with other calls to pseudo-random
>   sequence generation functions. The implementation shall behave as if no library function
>   calls the **srand** function.

C++ includes `rand`, `srand` and `RAND_MAX` without change by reference from the C standard.
There are a few C++ library functions/classes which are explicitly documented to use the C random number generator though.

Comment: Thanks Dedupicator for your detailed answer. The reason why I asked about differences between C and C++ is the comment under "compatibility" of [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/). Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 3):

The following answer is for C; specifically, the 1999 standard.

The C99 standard is very light on actual implementation details for `rand` & `srand`.  It simply states that the argument to `srand` is used "as a [seed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed) for a new sequence of pseudo-random numbers to be returned by subsequent calls to `rand`."

In practice, the way it usually works is:

- The C library defines an integer variable that `rand` and `srand` use to keep track of the PRNG's state.
- `srand` sets the state variable to the supplied value.
- `rand` takes the value of the state variable and performs some mathematical magic on it to produce two new integers: one is the pseudo-random number that it returns, and the other becomes the new value for the state variable, thus influencing the next call to `rand` (assuming `srand` isn't called before then).

The C standard gives an example of a possible implementation of `rand` and `srand` that exhibits this behavior:

```
static unsigned long int next = 1; 

int rand(void) // RAND_MAX assumed to be 32767 
{ 
    next = next * 1103515245 + 12345; 
    return (unsigned int)(next/65536) % 32768; 
} 

void srand(unsigned int seed) 
{ 
    next = seed; 
}
```

Comment: One important note is that since `next` is `static`, that it cannot be accessed or modified from outside of this translation unit.  Which was probably already compiled for you, so there's no (sane) way to interact with it.

Comment: Thanks jwodder and Mooing Duck. That certainly dispels my confusion, and also clarifies why are some implementations thread-unsafe since they may use static variables internally.