# How to generate random number from a given set of values?

Tags: c, random, srand

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int r=rand();
}
```

The above function can generate any number, but what if I want to generate a number from a given set of values.
For example if I want to generate a number randomly but ONLY from the values `4,6,1,7,8,3`.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `rand()` is allowed to be thoroughly bad: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005459/implementation-of-the-random-number-generator-in-c-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's pretty simple. Create an array. that has the outputs you desire (4,6,1,7,8,3). Then choose a random bucket in the array. `% 6` basically chooses values `0 - 5` which are the indices in your array.

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int myArray[6] = { 4,6,1,7,8,3 };
    int randomIndex = rand() % 6;
    int randomValue = myArray[randomIndex];
}
```

Some information on how you can manipulate `rand()` further.

`rand() % 7 + 1`

Explanation:

- rand() returns a random number between 0 and a large number.
- % 7 gets the remainder after dividing by 7, which will be an integer from 0 to 6 inclusive.
- 1 changes the range to 1 to 7 inclusive.

Comment: you mean `r = myArray[rand()%6]` right? otherwise why you defined `muArray` ?

Comment: @chouaib fixed it, to make more sense thanks. I got a little lazy.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a pre-defined set of values you want to choose from randomly, then put them in an array, and use `rand` to get the index into the array.

See e.g. [this old SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6852396/440558) for how to get a random number within a range (i.e. between zero and the size of the array for your case).

Answer (score 0):

You could get the list of random values that you want and store them in an array. Then you can choose a random number from the range of the list and choose the location at the specified index.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the random number and take only the leftover.
use is as a index of the array of your wanted numbers

For example , if you take the (random number % 3) you will get 0,1,2 
so you can use array of 3 wanted numbers