# Mastermind Issue with guess code

Tags: c++

Ok I have a school problem where I got to create a guessing game. the original number is a random five digit number and if they guess and get a number right it lets them know that one fo the numbers is correct, if the number is in the right spot it lets them know the number is correct and they have one in the correct position. Now I am kind of unsure where to take this my code has been half erased because I am confused as heck lol if someone can show me a tutorial or something I can read to teach me how to make something like this then thank you very much here is my messed up code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

void game(int);

int main(){

int a = 0;;
game(a);




system("pause");
return 0;
 }
  void game(int a){

srand(time(0));
int guess[5];
int answer;
int num1 = rand() % 9 + 1;
int num2 = rand() % 9 + 1;
int num3 = rand() % 9 + 1;
int num4 = rand() % 9 + 1;
int num5 = rand() % 9 + 1;

cout << "Your number is " << num1 << num2 << num3 << num4 << num5 << endl;

cout << "please guess a number";




if (guess[0] == num1 && guess[1] == num2 && guess[2] == num3 && guess[3] == num4 &&           guess[4] == num5){
    cout << "you have guessed correctly you win!!!!!\n";
}
}
```

ok I was thinking that I made ther guess an array and used a game loop,,but its the guessing part that is getting me, I do not understand how to have them put in 5 digits and compare it to 5 digits i have randomly generated

Comment: You know your formatting is shot? Please fix. Also, try to get line-length in code down to something sane, like 80 characters or so...

Comment: I said in the beggining I erased a good bit and messed somethings up. I just wanted to show some code. I just do not know how to get them to put in a 5 digit number  and compare it to the random one

Comment: Why do it complicated? Just let them input a number and compare that with your random number of 5 decimal digits. Use a `long` for portability. You might just let them retry if they input too many digits... Learn here how bad `rand()` is: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24005459 Consider using [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)

Comment: @Deduplicator  that is my issue bro I dont really know how to compare the numbers and our book has nothing about it...like if you guess 34253 i got to be able to tell u if any digits are correct and if any digits is in there correct places. thats what I do not understand how to do

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the input in two ways:  5 characters or as 1 number.
Let us consider the number.

**Isolating a digit**
The user will enter a number 0..99999.
To check a digit, you should isolate it by using *modulo* arithmetic (remainder) and division.

Given a number: 12345, let's isolate the digit 3.
First let's get the remainder when divided by 10 to the 3rd power, which is 1000.  This essentially removes the first two digits:

```
12345 % 1000 == 345.
```

To get the digit 3, let's divide the result by 100:

```
345 / 100 == 3.
```

You can compare this with you single digit you randomly generated.

**Comparing by character**
We can treat the input as 5 characters (a.k.a. letters or numbers).  This would be known as a string.

The random "numbers" or digits, can be converted to a character representation by adding the character '0' to them.  This lets us compare value in the same units, characters.

So if you want to compare the 3rd digit, you would compare to the 3rd character in the string:

```
std::string users_number;
char computers_guess[5];
if (users_number[3] == computers_guess[3])
{
  // tell user that one of the digits is correct and in the correct position.
}
```