# What is the function behind srand?

Tags: c, random, srand

I know this is a weird question, but I would really like to know what's behind the srand() function, just out of sheer curiosity. Is it possible to write a C code that has the same end or is it dependent on the machine itself? thank you for your help. XP

Comment: Behind the scenes, basically there's a seed and a pseudo-random generator function. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_generator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`srand()` *is* a function.

The details of its implementation can vary greatly from one implementation to another, but the ISO C standard provides a sample implementation of both `srand` and `rand`. See [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) section 7.22.3:

```
static unsigned long int next = 1;
                 // RAND_MAX assumed to be 32767
int rand(void)
{
      next = next * 1103515245 + 12345;
      return (unsigned int)(next/65536) % 32768;
}
void srand(unsigned int seed)
{
      next = seed;
}
```

It's important to note that this is not in any sense **the** implementation of the `rand` and `srand` functions; it's just one possible implementation, provided by the standard as an example.

Note that the sequence of "random" (actually pseudo-random) numbers resulting from calls to `rand()`, for a given seed passed to `srand()` is fixed. This is deliberate; it allows you to reproduce the same behavior for a program by using the same seed. These functions are typically not suitable for applications that require high-quality pseudo-random numbers.

For more information, see the excellent [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/), particularly questions 13.15 through 13.21.

Comment: i see, thank you. i knew it was a function, but i had no idea what was the code behind it (still don't fully understand it, but its a bit clearer now XP) once again thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The requirements on `rand` are:

- Generates pseudo-random numbers.
- Range is 0 to `RAND_MAX` (minimum of 32767).
- The seed set by `srand()` determines the sequence of pseudo-random numbers returned.
- It need not be thread-safe or even reentrant, the state can be stored in a static variable.

The standard does not define any way to recover the internal state for reseeding or anything else.

There is no requirement on what PRNG is implemented, so every implementation can have its own, though [Linear Congruential Generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) are a favorite.

A conforming (though arguably useless) implementation is presented here:

[image]

Excerpted from my earlier answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24005617/3204551

Answer (score 0):

Of course. `srand()` and `rand()` are written C.  What else?!

They use the simple idea of a linear congruential pseudorandom number generator:

```
X <- (a * X + b) mod m
```

The values `a`, `b`, and `m` are constants.  `srand(val)` establishes the initial value of `X`.  Every time you call `rand()`, it performs the calculation above and returns the new value of `X`.