# C++ Deeper look inside rand() and srand()

Tags: c++, random, random-seed

I know how `rand()` and `srand()` are related to each other, and I know how should I use them, but their mechanism of working was really interesting for me and I wanted to know *How they really work?!*, but I couldn't find any special thing.

So this is my question:  What is going on in deep inside of `rand()` and `srand()` and how does it produce a random number? (**If** it's really *producing* a random one!) Does it have any special mathematics calculation or any special algorithm? what is it?

Comment: Rand is implementation defined, although it's typically implemented as a linear congruential generator. However, well defined generators can be found in the standard <random> header. And are probably more worth looking at as rand is well known to _typically_ produce low quality random numbers.

Comment: If you want to know "*How they really work?!*" take a look at your standard library implementation

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005459/implementation-of-the-random-number-generator-in-c-c/24005617 for what the standard says, and what most implementations do. Be prepared to be severely disillusioned.

Comment: @George -- a bit hypertechnical, but the implementation of `rand()` is **implementation-specific**, not **implementation-defined**.  In the C and C++ standards, "implementation defined" means that a conforming implementation must document what it does. That's not required for `rand()`.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, `rand()` **does not** produce **random** numbers. It is a [Pseudo Random Number Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator).

`rand()` is *typically* implemented as [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). 
You can think that there is a variable `seed`, which holds previous state of generator, then `rand()` just uses this seed to generate next number in a sequence.

Something like this (very rough implementation, just to explain the idea):

```
const int RAND_MAX = 32767; // usually it is 2^15, but actually implementation specific
const int a = ...;          // implementation specific
const int c = ...;          // implementation specific
int seed = 0;               // current generator state

void srand(int _seed) {
  seed = _seed;
}

int rand() {
  int r = (a * seed + c) % RAND_MAX;
  seed = r;
  return r;
}
```

It will create the same sequence for the same initial state (seed value).

Comment: "`rand()` is implemented as linear congruential generator", usually true but it's not a standard requirement.

Comment: Off-by-one error -- `RAND_MAX` is the maximum value that can be generated, so the remainder should be `RAND_MAX + 1`. Also, "usually it is 2^15" is, I think, overstated; it has to be at least 2^15, but the simplest implementation is to just use the hardware directly, which drops overflow bits, i.e., with 32-bit registers RAND_MAX is most naturally 2^31. +1.